# Re-upload same file shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I am following the [simple file upload example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) from shiny gallery, but with a slight modification. I am required to modify the csv files locally, and see the changes reflected on the UI. However, I believe that this is not possible unless we poll for any changes in the source.

Therefore, I simplify the problem, by allowing re-uploading of the file. But, this is also not happening in Shiny. Once a file "file1.csv" is uploaded, i cannot upload the same file again. I have to upload a different file "file2.csv" and then once again the original file "file1.csv".

This is just time consuming, and I am wondering if anyone has come across such an issue, and possibly found a solution for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a jquery to clear the value of the fileInput does the trick.

```
...
fileInput("csvInput", "Upload CSV file", multiple = TRUE,
              accept=c('text/csv',
                       'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                       '.csv')),
tags$script('$( "#csvInput" ).on( "click", function() { this.value = null; });'),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is one of the shortcomings of Shiny's `fileInput` module: it stays still if the same file was selected again, and there is no `force-upload` option built-in.

---

To enforce re-uploading, the basic idea is:

1. After each time uploading, keep the uploaded data in a `reactiveValues` as storage.
2. Apply a new `fileInput` to replace original one
3. Show a successfully upload message under new `fileInput` for a better user experience.

---

In `ui.R`,using

```
uiOutput('fileImport')
```

In `server.R`:

```
# reactive storage
v <- reactiveValues()
# fileInput index
v$fileInputIndex <- 1

updateFileInput <- function (name = NULL){
  # update output with a new fileInput module
  output$fileImport <- renderUI({
    index <- isolate(v$fileInputIndex)
    result <- div()
    result <- tagAppendChild(
      result,
      fileInput(paste0('file', index), 'Choose CSV File',accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv'))
    )
    # show a message of successful uploading
    if(!is.null(name)){
      result <- tagAppendChild(
        result, 
        div(name," upload complete")
      )
    }
    result

  })
}

dataInputRaw <- reactive({
  # equals to `input$file1` when initialized
  inFile <- input[[paste0('file', v$fileInputIndex)]]

  # TICKY PART:
  # 1. If initialized, `inFile` and `v$data` are both `NULL`
  # 2. After each uploading, new `fileInput` is applied and
  #    we want to keep previous updated data.
  #    It also prevent recursive creation of new `fileInput`s.
  if (is.null(inFile)){
    return(v$data)
  }

  # load as data frame
  v$data <- data.frame(read.csv(inFile$datapath))

  # if file successfuly uploaded, increate the index
  # then upload `fileInput` with successful message
  if (!is.null(v$data)){
    v$fileInputIndex <- v$fileInputIndex + 1
    updateFileInput(name = inFile$name)
  }

  # return data
  v$data
})

# init 
updateFileInput()
```

I have tested this snippet and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not able to use reactiveValues(). I am using observer({ }) function, that doesn't mix well with reactive({ })